# How To Prevent Interface Builder From Adding Items To A Custom View?

Tags: swift, uiview, interface-builder

**UPDATE:** Edited for clarity.

This is not a showstopper, but it is annoying, and I'd like to figure out how to address it.

I have a custom UIView. A UIScrollView, to be precise, that is programmatically populated with a bunch of UIViews at runtime. It is not meant to have anything embedded in Interface Builder (IB).

What happens with any UIView, is that when you drag another element over it, the UIView becomes "droppable," and allows the other element to be dropped into it.

There are a few native Apple elements that won't let you drop stuff into them, like UIPickerView.

Is there a flag or something I can set, so that it won't allow IB to add anything to it?

Like I said, not a showstopper. If stuff gets added, it is destroyed before the programmatic population happens, but it just seems "neater" to make it clear that it's not "droppable."

**UPDATE:** In the screengrabs below, the Login Picker View is a standard UIPickerView, and the Display Results Scroller View is my custom scroller. If I drag something out of the Library, and try to drop it on the Picker View, nothing happens. However, I am able to drop it into my Display Results View.

What I want, is to be able to declare my Display Results View as a "no fly zone," so it is no longer droppable.

I hope that makes it clear.

[image: Cannot Drop On PickerView]

Cannot Drop onto A PickerView

[image]

Can Drop On My Custom View

Comment: Your question is very light on details. Anything that could help us actually *duplicate* what you are asking is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Let me explain. Auto layout doesn't **add items** to anything. (At least as I know.) So consider me confused... what are you annoyed about?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant Interface Builder, not Auto Layout, since that's what he talks about in the body of the post. I have edited the title and tags accordingly.

Comment: OK. Sorry. It's deliberately light on details, because it would be overkill to attach an app. I guess I could make a couple of screengrabs, but I'm not sure they would make anything clearer. I'll edit the question, and see if I can clear it up a bit.

Comment: BTW: Just wanted to thank you guys for the downvote. We have a nasty habit of punishing people for asking questions, which may explain why so many members have enormous SO scores, with 1 question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is a great solution, but if you're using a storyboard (not a xib) then it seems to work…

1. In your storyboard, instead of dragging a scroll view out of the library, drag out a container view.
2. IB automatically creates a new storyboard scene connected to the new container view by an embed segue. Delete the newly-created scene.
3. Set the container view's custom class to `UIScrollView`.

IB does not allow you to add any subviews to a container view.

Note that IB also doesn't show you any `UIScrollView`-specific properties in the Attributes inspector, so if you need to customize this funky scroll view, you have to do it programmatically.

The library doesn't offer the container view in a xib, hence the storyboard requirement.

Comment: Thanks! That won't solve my issue, but I'm already fixed on a scroller. I add a bunch of results from a server query into it, setting up Auto-Layout programmatically. It's fairly straightforward and simple.

Comment: Why doesn’t this solve your problem? It puts a scroll view in your scene, and IB won’t let you add subviews to that scroll view. If you’re using a custom subclass of `UIScrollView`, use your custom subclass’s name in step 3.

Comment: Incidentally, it sounds like you should really be using a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`, not a ,UIScrollView`.

Comment: Yeah, I've usually used UITableViews for this kind of thing, but that requires that I implement everything as a UITableViewCell, and I'd be best served creating more IB assets. I would probably do that if this were a shipping app, but this is just a test harness, and I want to have a lot of flexibility in what I dump in there. It was also a "teacher" for programmatically populating a scroller; something that I had avoided by using tables and collections. Like I said, not a big deal.

Comment: BTW: Forgot to answer your question. It doesn't solve my issue, because it makes it a bit more complex, in which case, a UITableView would probably be a better approach. This is a status display in a test harness. It was something I wanted to be able to toss into a quick n' dirty without spending any time on it. It just made me curious about that drag&drop target thing. I don't care for this instance, but I write a lot of frameworks and whatnot, and it could be more useful in those cases.